# Operator overloading changes operands

Tags: c#, operator-overloading, operator-keyword

*This is my try to explain my previous question more, since the previous one didn't get the answers I need.*

Suppose I have two classes, the first class is a Symbol, it has a char, (double)coefficient, and (double)power. Overloading the minus operator is in this way:

```
public static Symbol operator -(Symbol symbol)
    => new(symbol.symbol, -symbol.Coefficient, symbol.Exponent);
```

And I have the following code:

```
Symbol sym = new('x', 3, 1);
Console.WriteLine(-sym); // output: -3*x
Console.WriteLine(sym);  // output: 3*x
```

At this point, it all makes sense, but when I have the second class, Polynomial, that is a list of symbols, and I have the following minus overloading function:

```
public static Polynomial operator -(Polynomial polynomial)
{

    Polynomial result = polynomial;

    for (int i = 0; i < result.container.Count; i++)
        result.container[i] = -result.container[i];

    return result;
}
```

> The container[i] here is a Symbol object.

When I execute the following:

```
Console.WriteLine(polynomial); // output: 3*x + 2*y
Console.WriteLine(-polynomial); // output: -3*x - 2*y
Console.WriteLine(polynomial); // output: -3*x - 2*y
```

> Whereas the last expected output should be '3*x + 2*y'

So what I should do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a new instance of `Polynomial` just like what you did in the `Symbol` class.

```
public static Polynomial operator -(Polynomial polynomial)
{
    Polynomial result = new Polynomial { container = new List<Symbol>() };

    for (int i = 0; i < polynomial.container.Count; i++)
        result.container.Add(-polynomial.container[i]);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: It worked just fine! Just one edit, it polynomial.container.Count, because the result's one is still empty :) But thank you so much!

Comment: My mistake, corrected.

Comment: I just have another question, what if I can instance the object, wouldn't it work my way?

Comment: Because `List<>` is a reference type, it's not automatically cloned. The same `container` is refered by both `result` and `polynomial` if you don't create a new one.

Comment: Understand! Thanks for your help!